# Static sources not supported for video yet

Tags: python, pyglet

I was trying to play a song using Pyglet, but encountered this error

NotImplementedError: Static sources not supported for video yet.

But the file is mp3 format. I have AVbin11-win64.exe installed (avbin64.dll) which is copied in 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64' Folder, downloaded from https://github.com/AVbin/AVbin/downloads.

Here is the script I am using :

```
import pyglet
player = pyglet.media.Player()
source = pyglet.media.load(r'C:\Users\MANDAV\Desktop\New folder (2)\Diamond-
Platnumz-All-The-Way-Up-v2.mp3', streaming=False)
player.play()
player.app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains a few issues.
The first being `player.app.run()`, player doesn't have `.app` - you're probably looking for `pyglet.app.run()`.

The second thing is that you try to call `player.play()`, but you never did `player.queue(source)`. So either do `source.play()` or `player.queue(source)` (both does exactly the same thing, playing the source directly will create a player in the background.)

The third thing being `streaming=False`. avbin (10 at least) have issues decoding mp3 as a static source. Not quite sure why, but the project has been dead for soon to be a century (yes, in just a few short years, this code has been dead for 10 years).

Here's a minimal working example:

```
import pyglet
source = pyglet.media.load('epic.mp3')
source.play()
pyglet.app.run()
```

Altho, you probably want some more functionality while playing your stuff. So here's a bigger example of how you could put together a start for a music playing application:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *
from collections import OrderedDict

key = pyglet.window.key

class main(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__ (self, width=800, height=600, fps=False, *args, **kwargs):
        super(main, self).__init__(width, height, *args, **kwargs)

        self.keys = OrderedDict() # This just keeps track of which keys we're holding down. In case we want to do repeated input.
        self.alive = 1 # And as long as this is True, we'll keep on rendering.

        ## Add more songs to the list, either here, via input() from the console or on_key_ress() function below.
        self.songs = ['A.wav', 'B.wav', 'C.wav']
        self.song_pool = None

        self.player = pyglet.media.Player()
        for song in self.songs:
            media = pyglet.media.load(song)
            if self.song_pool is None:
                ## == if the Song Pool hasn't been setup,
                ##    we'll set one up. Because we need to know the audio_format()
                ##    we can't really set it up in advance (consists more information than just 'mp3' or 'wav')
                self.song_pool = pyglet.media.SourceGroup(media.audio_format, None)
            ## == Queue the media into the song pool.
            self.song_pool.queue(pyglet.media.load(song))

        ## == And then, queue the song_pool into the player.
        ##    We do this because SourceGroup (song_pool) as a function called
        ##    .has_next() which we'll require later on.
        self.player.queue(self.song_pool)
        ## == Normally, you would do self.player.eos_action = self.function()
        ##    But for whatever fucky windows reasons, this doesn't work for me in testing.
        ##    So below is a manual workaround that works about as good.

        self.current_track = pyglet.text.Label('', x=width/2, y=height/2+50, anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')
        self.current_time = pyglet.text.Label('', x=width/2, y=height/2-50, anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')


    def on_draw(self):
        self.render()

    def on_close(self):
        self.alive = 0

    def on_key_release(self, symbol, modifiers):
        try:
            del self.keys[symbol]
        except:
            pass

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        if symbol == key.ESCAPE: # [ESC]
            self.alive = 0

        elif symbol == key.SPACE:
            if self.player.playing:
                self.player.pause()
            else:
                self.player.play()

        elif symbol == key.RIGHT:
            self.player.seek(self.player.time + 15)

        ## == You could check the user input here,
        ##    and add more songs via the keyboard here.
        ##    For as long as self.song_pool has tracks,
        ##    this player will continue to play.

        self.keys[symbol] = True

    def end_of_tracks(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.alive=0

    def render(self):
        ## Clear the screen
        self.clear()

        ## == You could show some video, image or text here while the music plays.
        ##    I'll drop in a example where the current Track Name and time are playing.

        ## == Grab the media_info (if any, otherwise this returns None)
        media_info = self.player.source.info
        if not media_info:
            ## == if there were no meta-data, we'll show the file-name instead:
            media_info = self.player.source._file.name
        else:
            ## == But if we got meta data, we'll show "Artist - Track Title"
            media_info = media_info.author + ' - ' + media_info.title

        self.current_track.text = media_info
        self.current_track.draw()

        ## == This part exists of two things,
        ## 1. Grab the Current Time Stamp and the Song Duration.
        ##    Check if the song_pool() is at it's end, and if the track Cur>=Max -> We'll quit.
        ## *  (This is the manual workaround)
        cur_t, end_t = int(self.player.time), int(self.player.source._get_duration())
        if self.song_pool.has_next() is False and cur_t >= end_t:
            self.alive=False

        ## 2. Show the current time and maximum time in seconds to the user.
        self.current_time.text = str(cur_t)+'/'+str(end_t) + 'seconds'
        self.current_time.draw()

        ## This "renders" the graphics:
        self.flip()

    def run(self):
        while self.alive == 1:
            self.render()

            # -----------> This is key <----------
            # This is what replaces pyglet.app.run()
            # but is required for the GUI to not freeze
            #
            event = self.dispatch_events()

x = main()
x.run()
```

If you're just interested in playing sounds.
I wholeheartedly recommend [Pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub).

Not only does it use [libav](https://libav.org/) which is more of a defacto standard when encoding and decoding, but it's also rich in features. Such as converting `.mp3` to `.wav` and you can control audio gain, play two sources at the same time etc.

Comment: I encountered a new issue, I am still using Pyglet, when I play a bunch of files, some random audio file pauses/freezes automatically at any random point. I have no idea what is causing it. Can you help me?